# How to get absolute URL parh without files

Tags: java, file, url, jsoup, absolute-path

I need get absolute path of links without links to files. I have this code which get me links and some links there missing.

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    URI uri = new URI("http://www.niocchi.com/");
    printURLofPages(uri);
}

private static void printURLofPages(URI uri) throws IOException {
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(uri.toString()).get();
    Elements links = doc.select("a[href~=^[^#]+$]");

    for (Element link : links) {
        String href = link.attr("abs:href");
        URL url = new URL(href);
        String path = url.getPath();
        int lastdot = path.lastIndexOf(".");
        if (lastdot > 0) {
            String extension = path.substring(lastdot);
            if (!extension.equalsIgnoreCase(".html") && !extension.equalsIgnoreCase(".htm"))
                return;
        }
        System.out.println(href);
    }
}
}
```

This code get me following links:

```
http://www.enormo.com/
http://www.vitalprix.com/
http://www.niocchi.com/javadoc
http://www.niocchi.com/
```

I need get this links:

```
http://www.enormo.com/
http://www.vitalprix.com/
http://www.niocchi.com/javadoc
http://www.linkedin.com/in/flmommens
http://www.linkedin.com/in/ivanprado
http://www.linkedin.com/in/marcgracia
http://es.linkedin.com/in/tdibaja
http://www.linkody.com
http://www.niocchi.com/
```

Thanks a lot for advices.

Comment: The URI class has everything you need; have you had a look at its javadoc?

Comment: Also, from a URI path alone, you cannot readily determine whether this path is a "directory" of a "file" at all

Comment: Is there some good way how to check it if it's file or not?

Comment: No.  The best you have is dodgy heuristics based on the path.  Even attempting to fetch a URL doesn't reliably tell if it refers to a file or not.

Comment: I updated code which get absolute path but missing me some other links. I don't know where is mistake. Thanks a lot for advices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of

```
String href = link.attr("href");
```

try

```
String href = link.attr("abs:href");
```

**EDIT** docs: http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/working-with-urls